# поиск переменной записи в файле скраппинга

Tags: python, requests, сессия

Написал код который проводит скраппинг/парсинг **(получает данные из страницы сайта)** и получает куки. Проблема в `sessionID` который постоянно меняется и мне нужно передавать в следующую функцию автоматом.

В **SQL** есть финт с `like = %456` где поиск идет по всем данным содержащим в конце **456**. Есть ли в питоне подобная логика?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск в начале строки startswith
Поиск в конце строки endswith

```
st = '1231241456'
print(st.startswith('456'))
print(st.endswith('456'))
```

Вывод:
False
True